# Copy string to const char inside a class

Tags: c++

Any reason why this gives unexpected output?

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass(string item)
        {
            _item = item.c_str();
            std::cout << "Constructor: " << _item << endl;
        }

        void printItem()
        {
           std::cout << "Print:" << _item << endl;
        }

    private:
        const char* _item;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyClass my("www.somewebsite.com");
    my.printItem();
    return 0;
}
```

When I pass a short text such as "abc" into the constructor, I get the expected output:

```
Constructor: abc
Print: abc
```

But if I enter something longer like the web address "www.somewebsite.com, I get:

```
Constructor: www.somewebsite.com
Print:
```

My output really is quite random.

Comment: Why not store an `std::string` to begin with? You completely unnecessarily complicate stuff with your `const char*`.

Comment: I don't think it's valid to extract the data pointer from a string and user it after its destruction!

Comment: @pascx64 Agree, after construction item goes out of scope, what _item will point to is undefined.

Comment: Yes this is more complicated than it should be but it's an out of context example. These are constraints I've been asked to work. I'm passed strings and need to store char * for use with older internal library. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @chris358: either your constraints are wrong, or you misunderstand them. In any case, store a `string` inside the class itself, and use its `c_str()` method when interacting with the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it was already pointed out, the contructor is taking the string by value and you're assigning a pointer to it. So, when the contructor returns, the string is destroyed and your pointer becomes meaningless.

What you need to do it to copy the value of the string like this:

```
const char* cStr = item.c_str();
_item = (char*)malloc(strlen(cStr) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(_item, cStr);
```

This way, your pointer will be pointing to a new memory block.

Answer (score 4):

Your constructor takes a `string` *by value*. You then assign a pointer to the underlying data of the `string` to your `_item` member.

After the constructor returns, the `item` parameter goes out of scope and is destroyed, leaving your `_item` pointer dangling, pointing at now-invalid memory.

You should change your `const char* _item;` to `std::string _item;`. Then you can simply copy the string in your constructor.

```
MyClass(string item)
{
    _item = item;
    std::cout << "Constructor: " << _item << endl;
}
```

Or even initialize it with an initializer list

```
MyClass(string item) : _item(item)
{
    std::cout << "Constructor: " << _item << endl;
}
```